# Homestead.yaml Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array

Tags: laravel, homestead

I cannot run vagrant due to this error. I've posted my homestead.yaml code image.

[image]

Comment: Instead of including images of your code, please copy and paste the code into the answer. This will help others answer your question by being able to copy your code and run it themselves. This will also help future people with the same question to find your question by searching. Finally be specific in what the error is and where it is located at.

Comment: I don't believe the issue is your Homestead.yaml file.  I think it has to do with the location of it.  I would look into [per-project](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#per-project-installation) installations

Comment: What folder location are you running `vagrant up` in ?

Comment: Have you added the homestead snippet to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` to allow homestead to be run globally?

Answer (score 0):

Per your screenshot it looks like the last line of your yaml file is not correctly indented (you have extra space before `value`). It must be

```
variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```